# how to change react native android picker background

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-picker

[image]

[image]

All of them work except the background, but I couldn't get the background color to work. All I want is #000 for the background, but no matter what I tried, colorBackround popupBackround etc. I tried all of them but it didn't work. Everyone on the internet gave the same link. I've been trying for about 5 6 hours, but I couldn't change the background color.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#151617</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#151617</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
</style>


<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000</item>
</style>

<item name="android:background">@drawable/mydivider</item> // I tried that too, it didn't work
```

When I run it like this, all items are centered, a white page comes up background white texts white what I want is black background white text

Answer (score 0):

Your background custom code seems to be in the wrong place.

```html
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">#151617</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#151617</item>
    <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/rn_edit_text_material</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/SpinnerItem</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/SpinnerDropDownItem</item>
</style>


<style name="SpinnerItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
</style>

<style name="SpinnerDropDownItem" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18dp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:background">#000</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/mydivider</item> // here
</style>
```

Comment: I already used it where you pointed it out. If you look at the picture above, I used that code in the right place. I showed it as an example, I used it as well but didn't work.